# Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS Mouse clicks

Tags: mouse

This seems to be a common issue in older versions but nothing I could find would solve issues in this version. My first real foray into Ubuntu or Linux so forgive any stupid questions :)

My mouse clicks left or right, only work for a short period, maybe 4-5 clicks then nothing. Keyboard works fine. New install, oddly it did the same thing during install from USB as well.

mouse is 100% functional in windows, so not likely a hardware issue. compiz --replace will start the 4-5 timer over, but only works about 4 times after this I have to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

can you try, below command and see if it comes back. to do so press ctrl+alt+T key combination together and command window will open and type below command

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

see if this brings backs your mouse.